# Я пишу margin для 1 класса а применяется к другому

Tags: css, html5

Что делать когда пишу padding-bottom: 150px; то он применяется картинке, пытался класс самому h1 присвоить и самому отдельному блоку, сразу скажу марджин вправо влево работает а вниз нет вот код -

не разобрался как вставить код

Comment: Попробуйте написать для родителя написать `padding: 0.02px;`. P.S. Родитель - это тот тег, в котором лежит тег h1

Comment: не работает, все пробовал

Comment: выложите фрагмент верстки. и попробуйте `padding-top: 0.1px`, `padding-bottom: 0.1px`

Comment: [ссылка](https://codepen.io/LordOFtheCodee/pen/eYpVpgZ)

Comment: нарисуйте, что хотите. Я как понял хотите слева картинку, справа название и текст?

Comment: _когда пишу padding-bottom: 150px; то он применяется картинке_ - куда пишешь?